# Save global variable on Long Running Service

Tags: android, service, global-variables

I am trying to make chat application based on Android. I use nkzawa socket.io to connect node.js server. I need this socket keep alive for long time so I store this socket object in the service. This socket object is used for most activities so I make the object static and retrieved on static getter method.

I also need to store global variables and I decide to store them in this service. I make sure that whenever the service is destroyed, I saved all these variables to shared preference.

Is this good design approach?
I do really need some insight on this problem

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static variable will not be destroyed even your service is destroyed,because the lifetime of static variable belong to class,not object.If you want to destroy your object when service is destroyed,you can define a normal variable,getting it by mode called "aidl".